# .Net 5 Entity Framework removing unneccessary calls from Query involving FK 1:M relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have the following 2 DTOs that are used to return the information in the API in order to filter out fields that I don't want the client to be able to view

```
public record CommentDto
{
    public int? CommentId { get; set; }
    public string AuthorUid { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCommentId { get; set; }
    public string CommentPn { get; set; }
    public virtual UserDto User { get; set; }
}

public record UserDto
{
    public string Uid { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

I'm querying the postgres database using the following:

```
            var comments = await dbSet.
            Where(c => c.commentPn == sentPn)
           .Select(c => new CommentDto
            {
                CommentId = c.CommentId,
                CommentPn = c.CommentPn,
                AuthorUid = c.AuthorUid,
                Text = c.Text,
                ParentCommentId = c.ParentCommentId,
                User = new UserDto
                {
                    Username = dbSet.Select(u => u.User.Username).Single(),
                    Uid = dbSet.Select(u => u.User.Uid).Single()
                },
            }).ToListAsync();
```

While this works and the correct data is returned, I notice what I believe are unnecessary call(s) being included in the query.

```
  SELECT d1.comment_id AS "CommentId", d1.comment_pn AS "CommentNiin", d1.author_uid AS "AuthorUid", d1.comment_text AS "Text", d1.parent_comment_id AS "ParentCommentId", (
      SELECT u.username
      FROM database_item_comments AS d
      INNER JOIN users AS u ON d.author_uid = u.uid
      LIMIT 1) AS "Username", (
      SELECT u0.uid
      FROM database_item_comments AS d0
      INNER JOIN users AS u0 ON d0.author_uid = u0.uid
      LIMIT 1) AS "Uid"
  FROM database_item_comments AS d1
```

I know it's due to the way I'm retrieving the user values being incredibly inefficient, what would be the correct way to complete this query while only making a single call to the users table?

Preferably just querying the comment table directly, and returning the full Comment entity sans DTO, without having to map the variables, while creating the UserDto for the Comment and mapping the values

Comment: Add a navigation Comment.User to your entity class and use `c.User.UserName` etc in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Comment entity should have a reference to a User entity, which would see your query corrected to:

```
        var comments = await dbSet.
        Where(c => c.commentPn == sentPn)
       .Select(c => new CommentDto
        {
            CommentId = c.CommentId,
            CommentPn = c.CommentPn,
            AuthorUid = c.AuthorUid,
            Text = c.Text,
            ParentCommentId = c.ParentCommentId,
            User = new UserDto 
            {
                UId = c.User.UId,
                Username = c.User.Username
            });
        }).ToListAsync();
```

Your example would potentially fail if you have multiple comments in the DB as to populate the user DTO you were effectively telling it to load *all* comments (`DbSet.Select`) to get at the User and expect only 1 result via `Single()`. Then there is the fact that you are executing that twice, once to select the ID, and then to select the name.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been practicing C# by migrating a Golang project, but man with all the near identical version names (.net, .net3/4/5/6, .net core, web api etc..) I've had difficulty finding information that is either updated or relevant to what I'm using.

Comment: Yeah, .Net Core is regrettably a mess IMO as features in Core v2 were like a pre-alpha waiting on 3.1, which became an alpha waiting on 5, which was like a Beta waiting on a final real release with 6... All the while teams are trying to build production-ready code!!  It doesn't help that you have EF4/5/6 with EFCore now 5/6 :) .Net framework used to be something that was proprietary & updated every 2-3 years by MS, and the migration was remarkably painless, plus it was well documented when released. Now, like most OSS, the documentation is an afterthought.